# Opensource duplicate finder for directories?

Tags: windows, file-management

Is there an open source tool that will tell me if two directories have byte-for-byte identical content?  I need a tool that confirms if two directories are the same.  A listing of files that I need to sort through is very time consuming to sort through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinMerge will compare two directories (recursively if you like) and tell you which items are different.  I find it useful to go into the options and disable showing identical items.  This allows the differences to stand out.  If there are no differences it will tell you that too.

From the site: "[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/about/) is an Open Source differencing and merging tool for Windows. WinMerge can compare both folders and files, presenting differences in a visual text format that is easy to understand and handle."

Comment: Ah, you answered before mine so I've promoted your answer

Answer (score 1):

The first response in google is [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).  Does that fit the bill - open source and folder comparison?